# Array to String conversion Error in Laravel vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have already posted before with no real replies so I am trying again. I am trying to build a simple table to read data from a mongodb database which will be retrieved by using a query builder in laravel the data needs to be displayed with a vue component but when I try to load up the page an error message comes up:
The full error message if needed : Edit now the error has been fixed the new problem is that no data is being displayed just the titles of the table

```
   ErrorException 

   Array to string conversion

   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php:416
  412▕     protected function getResourceAction($resource, $controller, $method, $options)
413▕     {
414▕         $name = $this->getResourceRouteName($resource, $method, $options);
415▕ 
➜ 416▕         $action = ['as' => $name, 'uses' => $controller.'@'.$method];
417▕ 
418▕         if (isset($options['middleware'])) {
419▕             $action['middleware'] = $options['middleware'];
420▕         }

   +14 vendor frames 
   15  routes/api.php:20
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()

   +3 vendor frames 
   19  routes/api.php:21
   Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar::group()
```

Here is the code I have used if you wish to replicate:

api.php route:

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
Route::resource('/home', [ProductController::class,'home']);
});
```

web.php route:

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {
return view('home');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

PostController Home method:

```
public function home() {
    $posts = Post::paginate(4);

    return response()->json($posts);
}
```

Home component:

```
<template>
<div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
         <tr v-for="El in results" v-bind:key="El.id" >
             <td>{{El.id}}</td>
            <td>{{El.STATUS}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default{
     data() {
        return {
            results: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        fetch() {
            axios.get('/api/home')
                .then(response => this.results = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container" id="app">
<home-component></home-component>
</div>
@endsection
```

The code seems to be working fine the problem is starting at the api route handler but the why and how to solve it are beyond me. SO, Any and all help and suggestions are appreciated.
Edit: the original question was about an error which has since been removed but replaced with a new problem which is mentioned above.

Comment: `Route::resource('/home', [ProductController::class,'home']);` 
I think errors in here . You try change to `Route::resource('home', 'ProductController@home');`

Comment: It depends which version of Laravel you are using @Xupitan... In [Laravel 8.x + 9.x](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#the-default-route-files)... In [Laravel 6.x + 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#basic-routing)...

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using @Anshul Raj

Comment: Ahhh, I see your error. Will make an answer.

Comment: i 've checked document of resource route, it have not actions in `declare route`:
`Route::resource('photos', PhotoController::class);`
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Comment: Yeah I tried what you have suggested before there was no change but now I ma able to see the home.blade stuff including the table names in vue component but no data is actually being displayed

Comment: @Xupitan yes I agree with you and have done the same but the data is still not being shown thank you for the correction

Comment: Really @KurtFriars that would be great

Comment: Also for reference I am using laravel 8.83

Comment: @KurtFriars I am so sorry but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are providing too many arguments to the `Route::resource(...)` method.

The purpose of the `Route::resource` method is to define multiple routes and their corresponding controller actions according to the [resourceful controller pattern](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

In your case, you definitely are not using resourceful controllers since you have defined your controller action as `public function home()`. To fix this, you can simply define the `Route::get(...)` for the endpoint you are calling in your vue component.

```php
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [ProductController::class, 'home']);
});
```

Comment: Yeah see thats the problem when I do as you have mentioned above none of the data gets loaded meaning the web page only shows the title of the tables and nothing more

Comment: And I also checked to see if the json data is being loaded correctly and it is so no problems there I am really confused as to what I am missing in the vue component

Comment: @AnshulRaj well he answered your question, and your question was about routing issue which he answered that. in other hand your next problem is related to what you get in response. you're using `paginate` which in this case you should not use `results in v-for` check the response data, because there should be other fields related to following response. If you try to get data without paginate, then you might get your code work at front-end, in other-hand there are other fields and another structure to consider to handle your loop.

Comment: Oh the paginate was meant for me to see only some of the json data in actuality I am using the all() query when testing the code. And can you specify what do you mean by other fields and structure to consider to handle the loop

Comment: @AnshulRaj console.log(response.data) will lead you towards your further issue. This answer should be accepted, as it is the answer to the problem in your question.

Comment: @Atlas-Pio agreed but here is the post for the other problem I am facing any and all help is appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72347621/data-is-not-being-shown-on-the-vue-page