# Data is not being shown on the vue page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, eloquent

I have been working on making a simple vue js and laravel data displaying web page it is meant to display all the data in a table but I have had no such luck in doing so.
I am able to see all the json data when I go to the /api directory even the different pages I will need for pagination with all the page numbers is there but in the web page the data itself is not being displayed. I am not sure why and I have exhausted all the options I can find but I believe the vue component is the problem but the what I do not know. So, any help is much appreciated here is the code:
Home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container" id="app">
<home-component></home-component>
</div>
@endsection
```

HomeComponent:

```
<template>
<div v-if="Object.keys(results).length">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<table border="2">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td scope="col">Status</td>
        <td scope="col">DDC_CODE</td>
        <td scope="col">TRADE_NAME</td>
        <td scope="col">SCIENTIFIC_CODE</td>
        <td scope="col">SCIENTIFIC_NAME</td>
        <td scope="col">INGREDIENT_STRENGTH</td>
        <td scope="col">DOSAGE_FORM_PACKAGE</td>
        <td scope="col">ROUTE_OF_ADMIN</td>
        <td scope="col">PACKAGE_PRICE</td>
        <td scope="col">GRANULAR_UNIT</td>
        <td scope="col">MANUFACTURER</td>
        <td scope="col">REGISTERED_OWNER</td>
        <td scope="col">UPDATED_DATE</td>
        <td scope="col">SOURCE</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="El in results.data" v-bind:key="El._id" >
    <td>{{ El.STATUS }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.DDC_CODE }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.TRADE_NAME }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.SCIENTIFIC_CODE }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.SCIENTIFIC_NAME }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.INGREDIENT_STRENGTH }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.DOSAGE_FORM_PACKAGE }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.ROUTE_OF_ADMIN }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.PACKAGE_PRICE }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.GRANULAR_UNIT }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.MANUFACTURER }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.REGISTERED_OWNER }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.UPDATED_DATE }}</td>
    <td>{{ El.SOURCE }}</td>
     
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
    <pagination :data="results" @pagination-change-page="getResults" />
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default{

 data() {
    return {
        results: {}
    };
},
methods:{
    getResults(page=1){
        axios.get('/api/home?page='+page)
       .then(response=>{this.results=response.data ,console.log(this.results)}) 
       .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.getResults();
},


}
 </script>
```

api route:

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
Route::get('/home', [PostController::class, 'home']);
});
```

Web route:

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {return view('home');})->where('any', '.*');
```

PostController

```
public function home() {
    $posts = Post::paginate(4);

    return response()->json($posts);
}
```

Output when console logging response:
[image]

Comment: If you open up your browser's developer console, is there any information or errors there?

Comment: Yeah there is `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array 

found in

---> <Pagination>
       <HomeComponent> at resources/js/components/HomeComponent.vue
         <Root>`

Comment: You're assigning `results.data` to `this.results`. `results.data` is an array of the results, but not the full pagination object itself. Just assign `this.results = results`.

Comment: by `results.data` do you mean `response.data` sorry if this is a dumb question just want to be sure by what you mean

Comment: Also the console says the El is null so no data is actually being passed to the the results

Comment: Er, yes, `this.results=response.data` needs to be `this.results=response`

Comment: Edit: when I try `this.results=response` the El null goes away but the `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array 
found in
---> <Pagination>
       <HomeComponent> at resources/js/components/HomeComponent.vue
         <Root>` still stays but when I get rid of the line with the pagination and fix the mounted method no data is shown

Comment: Check the response in the Network tab, or add `console.log(response);` inside of your `then`. What does it show?

Comment: So when I console log I seen an Object and inside that there is data which contains another data where all the pages with each having 4 data points is present

Comment: I have added the output of the console log @aynber for your reference and also in the networks tab there are a lot of get request where one of them is to home?page=1 and it has transferred some kb of json data

Comment: As long as you're using `this.results = response`, and still passing `:data="results"` into the data component, then I'm not sure why it's still seeing an array instead of an object.

Comment: Yep thats kinds where I have reached as well

Comment: Also have a look at the new pic I have changed it to show the whole view of response

Comment: Okay, that shows the the structure better. `response.data` is what you need, which is an object. One thing you might want to try is `.then(({data}) => this.results = data)` which should be a shorter/easier way to get the response results.

Comment: When I do `.then(({data}) => this.results = data)`  I get el is null and the Invalid prop: data error but when I do the .then(response=>(this.results=response)) and change the result to an object essential `results:{}` I get no errors but also no data is displayed

Comment: Also when I console.log results it is empty I am console logging in the mounted area

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245012/discussion-between-anshul-raj-and-aynber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried `response.data.data` ?

By default there's a data field in response, until you add `WithoutWrapping` in provider.

Anyway, base on your code :

```
<script>
export default{
 data() {
    return {
        results: []
    };
},
methods:{
    getResults(page=1){
        axios.get('/api/home?page='+page)

       .then(response=>{
         this.results = response.data // Change this to response.data.data and try again
         console.log(this.results)
         // Console log the results no response to make sure what is happening here, 
         // or use Vue Dev Tools
})
       .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.getResults();
}
}
</script>
```

Since you might not added `WithoutWrapping` in provider, you might get following field in results when you tried `this.results=response.data` :

```
results : { 
 current_page : number,
 data: Array,
 first_page_url : string,
 // And more as you can see in picture you've attached.
}
```

If you've used `this.results = response.data.data`, then update `v-for` to `results` and comment `Paginate component` to debug component step by step.

Your problem might happen when you're using Paginate, because of props it got, so in this case, base on requirements you should change data you're passing to Paginate.

In other-hand, sharing paginate component code would be helpful to fix this issue.

When you've done debugging `v-for` with results of `response.data.data` you can modify the value you're sending to Paginate with changing `this.results = response.data` again.

Another thing is that, `Paginate Component` might not be flexible to any type of data it get, so when your component is ready, it might fail because, your `results` is an empty array.

Edit 01 : `I get a prop : data type check failed. What can I do as I am using the laravel-vue-pagination library do I have to call it as a component?? I am not sure what to pass as data`,

To answer this issue, here are the step, which i think you're facing them base on `laravel-vue-pagination` requirements and common issues that it's not predicted.

Now that we make sure where is this problem come from,

1. go ahead and change results to `this.results = response.data`
2. change `results` in `data` object to `results = {}`
3. pass `results.data` in `v-for` again, like before.
4. and now pass `results` in paginate component again.
5. this time also you can add a `v-if` condition to root element which it is `div`, to make sure you won't get errors again, in case you don't know, you can do like this :

```
<template>
<div v-if="Object.keys(results).length">
    // Table 
    // Paginate
</div>
</template>
```

The reason you're checking `results` is that :

1. Your `results.data`, is not exist, because you're defining it with an empty object(`results : {}`), so your `v-for` might fail or give you warnings.
2. I haven't used paginate component, but if you didn't considered possible issues with null/empty object/etc. then you should do it.
   Which in this case, base on our condition, both scenarios will be handled.

Comment: So thank you first of for answering to my post, now I tried the response.data and like you said I get all the information you mentioned an but only when result.data is passed into the for loop when I try with just result it gives an error that el is null which makes sense so I tried response.data.data and removed the result.data and made it just result which gives me the array into the results which is perfect but I get a prop : data type check failed. What can I do as I am using the laravel-vue-pagination library do I have to call it as a component?? I am not sure what to pass as data

Comment: @AnshulRaj I've updated answer, go ahead and check it from `Edit 01`.

Comment: @AnshulRaj I've also added more clarification for `v-if` statement.

Comment: I have tried as you have mentioned before but the problem is adding that if statement goes into the else clause as according to it the results object is empty . Why is this happening as when I pass `response.data.data` and check results an array of the data is present but when I do the same but with response.data and `results.data` in the loop it does not work?

Comment: I have also updated the code for you to see

Comment: You mentioned that you are not familiar with pagination that is fine the problem is the data itself is not being loaded

Comment: So a update I have gotten to code to run without any prop errors but I am getting a new json parse error if you ever get back to this post I will give more info

Comment: @AnshulRaj comments are going so long, so better to open a chat room in [stackoverflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com), to find out the issue, then I'll answer and point to the direct issue. open a new chat, send me the link in comment, I'll join to discuss about issue.

Comment: Actually I will be putting up a new post to show my new problem as this error technically solved and I am on to the next part of the problem

Comment: have a look at this link for the new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72372765/table-to-visualize-data-using-laravel-and-vue-js