# Table to visualize data using laravel and vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, pagination

I have been working on making a simple vue js and laravel data displaying web page it is meant to display all the data in a table but I have had no such luck in doing so I have already posted this question but the error has now changed so I am posting again. I am able to see all the json data when I go to the /api directory even the different pages I will need for pagination with all the page numbers is there but when I go to the console I get a Json Error:

```
Source map error: Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON 
data
Resource URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js
Source Map URL: laravel-vue-pagination.common.js.map
```

Not sure what this means or if it has any relevance to the data not being showed on the table or is there something else. Also when I load up the code editor my vue extension says it cannot find the `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json` in project file.

So, any help is much appreciated here is the code: Home.blade.php:

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container" id="app">
<home-component></home-component>
</div>
@endsection
```

HomeComponent:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Home component</div>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="post in laravelData.data" :key="post._id">{{ post.STATUS }}</li>
                </ul>

                <Pagination :data="laravelData" @pagination-change-page="getResults" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import LaravelVuePagination from 'shetabit-laravel-vue-pagination';

  export default{
   components: {
        'Pagination': LaravelVuePagination
  },
 data() {
  return {
    laravelData: {}
};
},

mounted(){
this.getResults();
},
methods:{
        getResults(page = 1) {
            axios.get('api/users?page=' + page)
                .then(response => {
                    this.laravelData = response.data;
                });
        }

},

}
</script>
```

api route:

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
Route::get('/home', [PostController::class, 'home']);
});
```

Web route:

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {return view('home');})->where('any', '.*');
```

PostController

```
public function home() {
    $posts = Post::paginate(4);

    return response()->json($posts);
}
```

Output when console logging response:
[image]

[image: Results output]
[image: Results.data]
[image: Error]
If you need the versions use
Laravel:8.83
vue:"^2.6.12"
laravel-vue-pagination:"^2.3.1"

Comment: i think the issue is on this line  'this.results=response.data' to be like this 'this.results=response.data.data' , because response has data default on axios

Comment: Yeah that is true but only when I am not using pagination with pagination this is the way it should be done here is the library reop for more info https://github.com/shetabit/laravel-vue-pagination and I need pagination as the data is otherwise to big

Comment: can share what is the output of this line in console .. 'this.results' after getting back from response

Comment: @SaravanaSai have a look at the post I have updated with the output of results

Comment: Also I have an error given by the extension saying that there is no tsconfig file which I believe is need for loading json data and could be causing the problem so any ideas what to do?

Comment: are you sure you're using [forked](https://github.com/shetabit/laravel-vue-pagination) ? here's the [original](https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination)

Comment: yes but that is meant for vue 3 so I am using the laravel-vue-pagination version 2.3.1 as mentioned in the end of the post

Comment: i don't get it, are you using the original or forked? there's also a original version for vue 2.

Comment: what error you've got when you use vue-paginate component? how you installed/import it?

Comment: I do not remember exactly but I realized now that bootstrap might be on an older version or not there at all so I php artisan ui bootstrap and now the error I get in the console is gone but still no data is being displayed

Comment: I used the original one but the steps are the same for both just the library and the versions should I try the forked?

Comment: here's the [original version for vue 2](https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination/releases/tag/2.3.2)

Comment: I think I will restart the whole thing from the installation of vue any ideas on how to get vue 3 from the start? as my laravel side of things works fine

Comment: you don't need to start a new project, I'll post an answer now.

Comment: Oh ok I will wait and try for awhile if in the end of all of this it still does not come to anything then I will retry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aright, I've just created a new project and everything was working so here's the steps which you can obviously ignore `Laravel` installation.

1. Composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test(you can ignore)
2. Composer require laravel/ui(you can ignore)
3. php artisan ui vue(you can ignore)
4. npm install && npm install shetabit-laravel-vue-pagination@2.3.2 (you can ignore, but make sure you install paginate)
5. npm update vue-loader (you can ignore)
6. Basic `VUE` setup in `app.js` as below : (you can ignore)

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;


import App from "./components/ExampleComponent.vue";
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App),
});
```

7. In `Example-Component.vue` : (don't forget to import your component in `VUE` component)

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="post in laravelData.data" :key="post.id">{{ post.fname }}</li>
                    </ul>

                    <Pagination :data="laravelData" @pagination-change-page="getResults" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import LaravelVuePagination from 'shetabit-laravel-vue-pagination';
    export default {
        components: {
            'Pagination': LaravelVuePagination
        },
        data() {
            return {
                // Our data object that holds the Laravel paginator data
                laravelData: {},
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            // Fetch initial results
            this.getResults();
        },

        methods: {
            // Our method to GET results from a Laravel endpoint
            getResults(page = 1) {
                axios.get('api/users?page=' + page)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.laravelData = response.data;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

8. `welcome.blade.app` Add Element and script tag to view, (I haven't added `CSS` because i only wanted to test `VUE` app)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center py-4 sm:pt-0">
            <div id="app"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

9. `api.php` (You should call your `API` via controller which is the recommended way, I've done this using `api.php` directly to don't waste time and lines of codes and description in here.)

```
Route::get('users', function () {
    $users = \App\Models\Product::paginate(4);
    return response()->json($users);
});
```

So, you've already installed your `Laravel` project, if you're not sure about your paginate component, just remove It like below :

```
npm uninstall package-name-in-package.json
```

And install it as i said :

```
install shetabit-laravel-vue-pagination@2.3.2
```

I haven't installed the original paginate to make sure you get what you want base on what you've installed before, to make sure you don't end to creating a new project or etc.

Edit 02 : [Github Link](https://github.com/braveshine1993m/vue-paginate-laravel-example)

Comment: Alright thank you I am going to try to delete and reinstall the package as you mentioned one question you are adding your paginate statement in the api.php while calling the Models file I am using a controller in between and calling paginate there should not change anything right?

Comment: no, keep your controller and do your api call just like before. I've just done that to make it faster to get the result. you don't need to get your items in `api.php` as i did. you do the regular way and use controller.

Comment: So as you have mentioned I tried but I got an error something to do with the home.balde.php as it is showing all of that code can you add what is in your blade file so I can test my code with it also I will update the code in the main post with what I have done now for you to see

Comment: @AnshulRaj `Blade view and App.js` part of answer, updated.

Comment: There is no call to the component in the blade file? sorry if this is a bad question but where are you calling the component

Comment: @AnshulRaj I've created a repository for this example. link is below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245023/discussion-between-atlas-pio-and-anshul-raj).

Answer (score 0):

I This error is caused due to  json you have returned from controller

you check out more at   [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse)

you can try this out  by adding in you controller response of getting post

```
response(json_encode($posts));
```

And Also try this out

```
getResults(page=1){
    axios.get('/api/home?page='+page)
   .then(response=>{this.results=JSON.parse(response.data) 
 ,console.log(this.results)}) 
   .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: Sorry man but I tried this and it does not work still no data I fixed the json error by downloading a new version of bootstrap but that does not seem like its enough

Comment: can you add that data object ....what acutally contains inside that ,sometimes this kind of issue comes from there tooo

Comment: Inside the data object is an array of length 4 containing all the data that needs to be displayed adding the picture soon

Comment: Have a look at the post

Comment: ok i have altered the answer ....plz check it out

Comment: Ok when I add the Json.parse I get a `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
    getResults HomeComponent.vue:64`

Comment: i had look it ...see in that response you have not getting the data what you have in you database ..... {_id: getter,setter ...}... it should not be like that ..i think it should be something like this {_id:1,STATUS:'something'}

Comment: dd($posts)  on you controller & add its image also .....

Comment: Have a look at the latest edit